# How do I fix this error where my compiler will not pick up the parameters I pass to a object declaration?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, error-handling, compiler-errors

**This Is The Point Super Class**

```
public class Point{
    
    Point(int x_pass,int y_pass)
    {
        x = x_pass;
        y = y_pass;
    }
}
```

**This Is The Quadrilateral Sub Class**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Quadrilateral extends Point{

    Quadrilateral(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4)
    {
        p_1 = p1;
        p_2 = p2;
        p_3 = p3;
        p_4 = p4;
    }
}
```

**This Is The Trapezoid Sub Class**

```
public class Trapezoid extends Quadrilateral{
    Trapezoid(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4)
    {
        super(p1,p2,p3,p4);
        p_2 = p3;
        p_1 = p1;
    }
}
```

**This Is The Driver**

```
public class Main extends Quadrilateral{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Trapezoid trap = new Trapezoid(new Point(1,5),new Point(5,5), new Point(2,7), new Point(4,7));
        System.out.println(trap.getArea());
    }
}
```

I'm using netbeans IDE 12.4 and Java JDK 16.0.1. For some reason I keep getting this error across all of my projects where the compiler does not pick up the parameters that I pass to a object declaration the error is bellow

> run:
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - constructor Quadrilateral in class quadrilateral.Quadrilateral cannot be applied to given types;
> required: quadrilateral.Point,quadrilateral.Point,quadrilateral.Point,quadrilateral.Point
> found:    no arguments
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
> at quadrilateral.Main.(Main.java:1)
> C:\Users\wtsth\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.4\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Users\wtsth\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.4\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Why does `Main` extend `Quadrilateral`?

Comment: And why does `Quadrilateral` extend `Point`? A `Quadrilateral` is not a `Point`, it contains 4 `Point`s.

Comment: @AliasCartellano they are all declared as private variables at the bottom of the class I assume you're talking about the point class when you refer to `x` it is declared as private int x, y; at the bottom of the point class.

Comment: @tkausl that doesn't make a difference from if I just extended `Trapezoid` it still can access all of the subclasses. It doesn't the problem I've tried a bunch of different extensions.

Comment: @ThomasKläger that was something I played a around with for a bit, I'm going to try to switch it up so `Point` extends `Quadrilateral`. But I don't believe this will solve my issue.

Comment: It won't solve your problem. A `Quadrilateral` is not a `Point` and therefore `class Quadrilateral extends Point {}` is wrong. But a `Point` is also not a `Quadrilateral` and therefore `class Point extends Quadrilateral {}` is also wrong. These two classes **must not be** in a parent class / sub class relationship! It must be `class Point {}` and `class Quadrilateral {}` (or, if you insist on writing an `extends` clause: `class Point extends Object {}` and `class Quadrilateral extends Object {}`). Similar for `Main`: `public class Main extends Object {}`

Comment: @ThomasKläger Ok, thank you for the explanation that makes sense, but do you know anything that could help fix my error?

Comment: @ThomasKläger never mind that actually did fix my error thank you I've been trying to figure this out for a bit.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).